# Is there a way to not include a negative number in an average, when entering a negative number is how you terminate the program?

Tags: c++

Sorry about last time for those who saw my previous thread. It was riddled with careless errors and typos. This is my assignment:

> > "Write a program that will enable the user to enter a series of non-negative numbers via an input statement. At the end of the input process, the program will display: the number of odd numbers and their average; the number of even numbers and their average; the total number of numbers entered. Enable the input process to stop by entering a negative value. Make sure that the user is advised of this ending condition."

And here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number, total1=0, total2=0, count1=0, count2=0;
    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number. The program will add up the odd and even ones separately, and average them: ";
        cin >> number;

        if(number % 2 == 0)
        {
            count1++;
            total1+=number;
        }
        else if (number >= 0)
        {
            count2++;
            total2+=number;
        }
    }
    while (number>=0);
        int avg1 = total1/count1;
        int avg2 = total2/count2;
        cout << "The average of your odd numbers are: " << avg1 << endl;
        cout << "The average of your even numbers are " << avg2 << endl;
}
```

It seems to be working fine, but when I enter a negative number to terminate the program, it includes it with the rest of the averaged numbers. Any advice to get around this? I know it's possible, but the idea escapes me.

Answer (score 2):

Your main loop should be like this:

```
#include <iostream>

for (int n; std::cout << "Enter a number: " && std::cin >> n && n >= 0; )
{
    // process n
}
```

Or, if you want to emit a diagnostic:

```
for (int n; ; )
{
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";

    if (!(std::cin >> n)) { std::cout << "Goodbye!\n"; break; }

    if (n < 0) { std::cout << "Non-positve number!\n"; break; }

    // process n
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After here:

```
cout << "Please enter a number. The program will add up the odd and even ones seperately, and average them: ";
cin >> number;
```

Immediately check if the number is negative

```
if(number < 0) break;
```

Now you wouldn't need to use your do-while loop in checking if the number is negative. Thus, you can use an infinite loop:

```
while(true) {
   cout << "Please enter a number. The program will add up the odd and even ones seperately, and average them: ";
   cin >> number;

   if(number < 0) break;

   // The rest of the code...
}
```

**ADDITIONAL**:
There is something wrong in your code. You aren't showing the user how much the number of even and odd numbers are, and the total number of numbers entered.

**ANOTHER ADDITIONAL**: You should use more meaningful variable names:

```
int totalNumEntered = 0, sumEven = 0, sumOdd = 0, numEven = 0, numOdd = 0;
```

Of course I am not limiting you to these names. You can also use other similar names.

**FOR THE INTEGER DIVISION PROBLEM**: 
You must cast your expression values to the proper type (in this case, it is `float`). You should also change the averages variables' types to `float`:

```
float avg1 = float(total1) / float(count1);
float avg2 = float(total2) / float(count2);
```

Comment: I noticed that something was wrong too. Where does my problem lie? Also, is there a way I would be able to initialize my values so I don't have to do integer division? My first if statement wouldn't start when I had my values initialized as doubles.

Comment: @AdamPawelski Please re-read my answer. It contains some edits.

Comment: @MarkGarciaThank you for the advice. I made the necessary changes and it improved a lot. However, the integer division is still bothering me. Any word or advice on it?

Comment: @AdamPawelski Sorry I took so long to respond. Please see the last edit.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after cin >> number, check for < 0, and break if so. Try to step through the program line by line to get a feel for the flow of execution. Have fun learning, and good luck!